# Convert Unicode to ANSI or UTF8 in python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, ansi

I am using Python 2.7.8 and I have a script which does parsing:

```
def parse():
    with open('myfile.txt') as f:
.
.
.
Print l
```

myfile.txt has a UNICODE coding. 
How can I add a code to this script so that it reads the myfile.txt as ANSI for example?

Comment: Why not use `unicode` internally instead? Use `io.open()` and specify the encoding.

Comment: Reading material: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html, https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html, and http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: [ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_National_Standards_Institute) - is not an encoding. Do you mean [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)? In that case, python opens in ASCII encoding by default.

Comment: @stalk: The OP is most likely referring to the [Windows code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page#ANSI_code_page), usually [CP-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: **Unicode is not an encoding** so the file can't be saved with a Unicode encoding. You might have UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: @Matthias, Martijn Pieters: Thanks

Answer (score 2):

using io solved my problem:

```
import io    
def parse()
    with io.open(path,'r',encoding='utf_16') as f:
.....
```

solved my problem.

Comment: HOLY FREAKING COW!!! Thanks so much! I've been looking for days and you have finally answered my question!